# Size of left coset, right coset and conjugate

Tags: group-theory

$H$ is a subgroup of $G$, is ti true that all left cosets, right cosets and conjugates have the same size as $H$?

Comment: Hint: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a bijection. For a subset $S\subseteq X$ what can you say about the "size" (cardinality) of $f(S)$ and $S$? For each $a$ what type of map is the map from $G$ to $G$ sending $x$ to $ax$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map from any left coset $gH$ to $H$ defined by $gh$$\mapsto$$h$ is a bijection. The same goes for right cosets $Hg$. For conjugates $gHg^{-1}$, use the map $ghg^{-1}$$\mapsto$$h$. Thus |$gH$|$=$|$Hg$|$=$|$gHg^{-1}$|$=$|$H$|.